# VB.NET - Paste URL of Web Image into Text Box

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, image

I need some help!

I've throroughly searched the web for a solution to my issue, but haven't got anywhere!

I'm looking for a way to copy and paste (or drag and drop) an image from the web into a text box within a VB.NET application. However, I'd like the URL of the image to appear, not the image itself.

OR

To be able to copy and paste (or drag and drop) an image from the web into a picturebox within a VB.NET application, and then have the URL appear in a text box.

Possible at all? You could say this is quite similar to iTunes, when adding custom artwork (basically pasting an image into a picturebox).

Also, I'm currently using Visual Studio 2010 to build my application.

Any help in this will be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had your same problem 2 weeks ago.
As far as I have understood, there is no way to do a drag and drop from an image taken from IE to a textbox.
But if you copy it and paste there is no problem and code to do it follows:

```
If My.Computer.Clipboard.ContainsImage Then
    imgMiniaturaGrafico.Image = My.Computer.Clipboard.GetImage
    txtMarchio.Text = "Marchio" & lblIDSocieta.Text & ".png"
    imgMiniaturaGrafico.Image.Save("C:\" & txtMarchio.Text, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
End If
```

If you want to copy the URL then you have to right click on the image, choose "properties" and copy its address from there.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks Andrea. How would this If statement be initialised? In other words, how would VB know that I'm using the paste function to allow this code to run?

Comment: Set in your form the property "AllowDrop" to True. Then write the following code:
  Private Sub Form1_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragDrop
    If My.Computer.Clipboard.ContainsImage Then
      PictureBox1.Image = My.Computer.Clipboard.GetImage
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub Form1_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragEnter
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All
  End Sub
In this way you will get every picture you copy and drop in the PictureBox control

Answer (score 0):

I add another answer, because the answer to your first question: "I'm looking for a way to copy and paste (or drag and drop) an image from the web into a text box within a VB.NET application. However, I'd like the URL of the image to appear, not the image itself." is straightforward:

1. Add a TextBox to your form
2. Run you project
3. Right click on an image in IE and select "Properties"
4. Select and copy the URL you see in "Address"
5. Right click on the TextBox in your project and select "Paste"

You got the URL in the TextBox.

I think their is not an easier way to get the URL of the image, except (maybe) navigating through a WebBrowser Control and parsing the document.